# Remove certain characters from write-host output in Powershell (Get-ADuser)

Tags: powershell, compare

I'm comparing users between two domains to make sure users that are disabled in one, are disabled in the other, using these two steps:

Domain 1:

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=ou2,OU=ou1,DC=pre,DC=domain1,DC=com" -Filter * -Properties * | Select-Object Name | Export-Csv -encoding "utf8" Users.csv
```

Domain 2:

```
$input = import-csv -path "Users.csv" 
ForEach ($User in $input) {
$result = get-aduser -SearchBase "OU=ou2,OU=ou1,DC=pre,DC=domain2,DC=com" -Filter "name -eq '$($User.Name)'" | Select-Object Enabled
If ($result -eq $null) { Write-host -ForegroundColor Yellow $User "Name not found. Please do a manual check" 
}
elseif ($result -like '*False*') 
{ 
Write-host -ForegroundColor Red "**" $User "** must be disabled!" 
}
else {get-aduser -SearchBase "ou=Users,ou=SCS,ou=All,dc=osit,dc=ad" -Filter "name -eq '$($User.Name)'" -Properties * | Select-Object Name, Enabled}
}
```

This works, but gives me the following output:

```
Name                          Enabled
----                          -------
Firstname1 Lastname1             True
@{Name=Firstname2 Lastname2} - Name not found. Please do a manual check
```

How do I remove "@{Name=" and "}"?
I have tried adding -ExtendProperity to $result, and Replace with no luck. I'm probably doing it wrong..

Comment: @{Name=Firstname2 Lastname2} is an array and not a string value.

Comment: @TobyU: It is the string representation of a _custom object_, not of an array.

Comment: Also, don't do `-Properties *` if all you are after are the `Name` and `Enabled` properties. These two properties are returned by default, as are `DistinguishedName, GivenName, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SamAccountName, SID, Surname, UserPrincipalName`, so you can skip the `-Properties *` alltogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$User` is a custom object (type `[pscustomobject]`, as output by `Import-Csv`), and `@{Name=Firstname2 Lastname2}` is its *stringified* representation<sup>[1]</sup>, because `Write-Host` stringifies its arguments for display.

Access the `.Name` property instead to get just the name:

```
Write-host -ForegroundColor Yellow $User.Name "- Name not found. Please do a manual check"
```

More idiomatically, using a single expandable string (string interpolation inside `"..."`):

```
Write-host -ForegroundColor Yellow  "$($User.Name) - Name not found. Please do a manual check"
```

If you want to include the full object representation as it would appear if you printed it directly to the console, you need `Out-String`, but note that you'll end up with *multi-line* output:

```
Write-host -ForegroundColor Yellow  "$($User | Out-String) - Name not found. Please do a manual check"
```

---

<sup>[1] You can verify this as follows: `$user = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = 'Firstname1 LastName1' }; "$user"`. The output is string `@{Name=Firstname1 LastName1}`.</sup>